# Get a range of data from MWNumericArray

Tags: c#, matlab

Suppose I have this in matlab:

```
>> x(:,:,1) = [ 1 2 3 ; 4 5 6 ];
>> x(:,:,2) = [ 7 8 9 ; 10 11 12 ];
>> x

x(:,:,1) =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6


x(:,:,2) =

     7     8     9
    10    11    12
```

I can index my 3d matrix to get all the data from the first "slice" :

```
>> y = x(:,:,1)

y =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
```

Now I am in C# working with a `MWNumericArray`. Is it possible to do the same thing, i.e. indexing the `MWNumericArray` to get all the rows and columns of the first (or any other) slice?

Comment: Downvoter, please explain?

Comment: I agree. You should leave comments while downvoting, unless it is obvious.